# Ember: catch not working with ember-data findRecord error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't figure out why I can't catch this error:

```
Assertion Failed: You made a 'findRecord' request for a 'cart' with id '3ea1901a-56a9-11e7-a8f4-60e147bfe84c', but the adapter's response did not have any data
```

This is happening when trying to add an item to my cart service, but there's a problem with the API.  Specifically, I am testing a security scenario where there's a token mismatch with the API.  The API will send back an empty response, which it is doing, but I want ember to `catch` that error and trigger a `addItemToNewCart` function.

This is the 'add' method:

```
// cart methods
add(item) {

    let self = this;

    // get cart from API first.  if this fails (in catch clause) a new one should be created
    return this.get('store').findRecord('cart', get(this, 'cartObj.id')).then(response => {

        console.log("RESPONSE", response.get('cartitems'));
        // check if cart already has lineitem
        let existingLineItem = response.get('cartitems').findBy('skuid', item.skuid);
        if (existingLineItem) { // if item is already in cart, just add more
            console.log("line item in response, adding quantity");
            set(existingLineItem, 'quantity', parseInt(existingLineItem.quantity)+parseInt(item.quantity))
        } else {
            console.log("line item not in response, adding new");
            response.get('cartitems').addObject(item);
        }
        // saving persists the cart back to API
        response.save().then(newCart => {
            set(this, 'cartObj', newCart);
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        // this is not firing even though there is an error
        console.log("problem with findRecord - create a new cart and add item to it", e.message);
        self._addItemToNewCart(item);
    });

},
```

It appears that somehow the ember-data promise is successfully resolving, because the console.log messages I have within the `then` block are being printed:

[image]

I am guessing `findRecord` is looking locally first, finding the cart, executing the `then` block and an async `findRecord` is coming in later with an error from the API (too late for the catch block), maybe?

If that's the case, how do I say, "wait for a response from the API before doing *anything* and if the response is empty, call `_addItemToNewCart`" ?

Comment: i would do this.store.findRecord(...).then(response => { // return new object if response meets condition });

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://emberigniter.com/force-store-reload-data-api-backend/)

Basically, need to add `{ reload: true }` to the ember-data find query

Comment: Actually your subject looks you want something different answer, any how I would encourage to read more on api docs too. that will have more detailed info than guides has. https://emberjs.com/api/ .. for your case findRecord look at https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html